# Mac intellij IDEA scala Code Completion

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-completion

Now I am coding in IDEA with scala, I have some problems.

scala code completion is case sensitive. For example:
when you type "sparkc" no code completion drop-down list
when you type "SparkC" drop-down list popup

[this setting is useful for java, but not for scala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXO5M.png)

First time asking question on SOF.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't describe the question, now the scala code completion is case sensitive, I want case insensitive. I found no settings for scala code completion in IDEA

Comment: Try [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/)? It built on Eclipse.

Comment: @merito I work with scala or java, don't want to install too many IDEs